# How to give onclick event for admin grid action link

Tags: admin, grid, magento2.2.6, action

I have a custom admin grid for return items. For which I need to add a popup to add a comment for every action below

[image: admin grid action]

I have written a js function for the modal popup. But I am unable to trigger **onclick** event for action links.
   I have tried below code in UI action file, it is not working.

[image]

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
     define([
        'mage/adminhtml/grid'
    ], function () {
        'use strict';

        return function (config) {

       /**
         * function
         *
         * @param {String} event
         */

        function customClickChange(event)
        {
            console.log('i m click');
            // do whatever you want here

        }

        /**
         * Initialize custom row
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {String} row
         */
        function customRowInit(grid, row)
        {
            var customAction = $(row).getElementsByClassName('classNameofYourAction')[0];

            if (customAction ) {

                Event.observe(checkbox, 'click', customClickChange);
            }

        }


        gridJsObject.initRowCallback = categoryProductRowInit;

        if (gridJsObject.rows) {
            gridJsObject.rows.each(function (row) {
                customRowInit(gridJsObject, row);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

You can get class name of your edit action by inspect element.
Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

**In first step we need to create block file :-**

```
<?php

namespace Yournamespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Product;

class CustomActionList extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $addButtonProps = [
            'id' => 'custom_action_list',
            'label' => __('Custom Action List'),
            'class' => 'add',
            'button_class' => '',
            'class_name' => 'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\SplitButton',
            'options' => $this->_getCustomActionListOptions(),
        ];
        $this->buttonList->add('add_new', $addButtonProps);

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve options for 'CustomActionList' split button
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getCustomActionListOptions()
    {
        /*list of button which you want to add*/
        $splitButtonOptions=[
        'action_1'=>['label'=>__('Action 1'),'onclick'=>'setLocation("ACTION CONTROLLER")'],
        'action_2'=>['label'=>__('Action 2'),'onclick'=>'setLocation("ACTION CONTROLLER")'],
        'action_3'=>['label'=>__('Action 3'),'onclick'=>'setLocation("ACTION CONTROLLER")']
        ];
        /* in above list you can also pass others attribute of buttons*/
        return $splitButtonOptions;
    }
}
```

**Now we call this block file in layout page where we want to add this split button :-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <!-- here we call our split button block   -->
            <block class="Yournamespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Product\CustomActionList" name="admin.product.customsplitbutton"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have tried your code. It gave the button with dropdown at the top of the grid. But I want separate action links for every row.

Comment: you can define action in block 'onclick'=>'setLocation("yor action")'

Comment: i have aleady written action controller for above links. But my requirement is to add comment for every action. For that iam trying to add popup

Comment: add comment for every action means ?

Comment: If for example, admin wants to reject the return request, then he needs to mention the reason for rejection. So, I want popup input field to write this reason.